# TFS Upgrade from 2008 to 2012 - Changes Checked Out but staff on leave

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

We are currently upgrading our team foundation server from 2008 to 2012 and have come across following issues:

1. There are staff on leave who have changes checked out to them. If we do, force undo checkout on their changes, what actually happens? Do they lose their changes?
2. What if we don't force undo checkout and bring everything across as it is, Can they just rebind their file to the new TFS and then checkin their changes?
3. Is there a way to do a force check-in? if yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, and also yes. The files are no longer marked as "checked-out", however they will still have a copy of the file locally that is now out of sync with the server copy.
2. Probably, especially if they change to local workspaces.
3. No, because you don't have the changes they've made. The best you can do is undo the checkout.